# How to build () => new { x.prop} lambda expression dynamically?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

[image]How to dynamically create the below linq expression.

**IQueryable abc = QueryData.Select(a => new { a, TempData = a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0] }).OrderBy(a => a.TempData).Select(a => a.a);**

```
public class Orders
{
    public long OrderID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public double Freight { get; set; }
    public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
    public string ShipCity { get; set; }

    public Customer[] customer {get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public string OtherAddress { get; set; }
    public int CustNum { get; set; }
}
```

Actual data:

```
List<Orders> order = new List<Orders>();
Customer[] cs = { new Customer { CustNum = 5, OtherAddress = "Hello" }, new 
Customer { CustNum = 986, OtherAddress = "Other" } };
Customer[] cso = { new Customer { OtherAddress = "T", CustNum = 5 }, new 
Customer { CustNum = 777, OtherAddress = "other" } };
order.Add(new Orders(code + 1, "ALFKI", i + 0, 2.3 * i, "Mumbari", "Berlin", cs));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 2, "ANATR", i + 2, 3.3 * i, "Sydney", "Madrid", cso));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 3, "ANTON", i + 1, 4.3 * i, "NY", "Cholchester", cs));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 4, "BLONP", i + 3, 5.3 * i, "LA", "Marseille", cso));
order.Add(new Orders(code + 5, "BOLID", i + 4, 6.3 * i, "Cochin", "Tsawassen", cs));



public Orders(long OrderId, string CustomerId, int EmployeeId, double Freight, string ShipCountry, string ShipCity, Customer[] Customer = null)
    {
        this.OrderID = OrderId;
        this.CustomerID = CustomerId;
        this.EmployeeID = EmployeeId;
        this.Freight = Freight;
        this.ShipCountry = ShipCountry;
        this.ShipCity = ShipCity;
        this.customer = Customer;
    }
```

If i sort the OtherAddress field 0th index means Customer field only sorted. I need to sort the whole order data based on OtherAddress field.

I have tried the below way:

```
private static IQueryable PerformComplexDataOperation<T>(this IQueryable<T> dataSource, string select)
    {
        string[] selectArr = select.Split('.');
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");
        Expression property = param;
        for (int i = 0; i < selectArr.Length; i++)
        {
            int n;
            if (int.TryParse(selectArr[i + 1], out n))
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt16(selectArr[i + 1]);
                property = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.ArrayIndex(Expression.PropertyOrField(property, selectArr[i]), Expression.Constant(index)), selectArr[i + 2]);
                i = i + 2;
            }
            else property = Expression.PropertyOrField(property, selectArr[i]);
        }
        var TempData = dataSource.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, param));

       IQueryable<object> data = dataSource.Select(a => new { a, TempData = property});// Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, param) });
        return data;
    }
```

Method call : **PerformComplexDataOperation(datasource, "customer.0.OtherAddress")**

I can get the value from this line : **var TempData = dataSource.Select(Expression.Lambda>(property, param));**

But i can't get the values in **dataSource.Select(a => new { a, TempData = property});**

It is working when we use the below code :

```
    var TempData = dataSource.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, param)).ToList();
    IQueryable<object> data = dataSource.Select((a, i) => new { a, TempData = TempData[i] });
```

Is it proper solution ?

Comment: Why? ..........

Comment: Ouch, you cannot be serious that you want this to be implemented without showing any effort? Learn how expressions work. Also who in his right mind is upvoting such a question?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe you are searching for something like AutoMapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: Hi @RandRandom I need to use the concept for some other data too that's why i asking

Comment: Hi @Icepickle i have tried but i didn't get any proper solution.

Comment: If you have tried then you should add your attempt here, it is simply to easy what you seem to expect

Comment: I can't able to create a => new { a,TempData} otherwise i will do my own

Comment: Hi @Icepickle Could you please share any usefull resources for dynamic expression. It will helpful to me to achieve my requirement.

Comment: You can't create anonymous types at runtime. But why you ever need that, if you take the equivalent simplified version w/o anonymous type like `QueryData.OrderBy(a => a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).FirstOrDefault())`, I guess you should have no problem building the expression dynamically.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev Thanks for your suggestion. I need to sort "customer.0.OtherAddress" nested file compared to whole base data. But it sorted only for that field. For this case, I find that field value and stored it to TempData. Then Sorting the TempData field. That's why i using anonymous type. If it is possible to achieve any other case.

Comment: I wrote a whole project about creating expression trees to copy properties (there were reasons why I couldn't use AutoMapper) including child objects and child collections. Its way to big to post here but the source of the latest version is https://github.com/markantill/PropertyCopier/tree/feature/alow-instance-based-mapping

Comment: @IvanStoev, actually you can create anonymous types at runtime, but it is tricky and of questionable usefulness.

Comment: Why are you doing `TempData = a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0]` when you could do `TempData = a.customer[0].OtherAddress` ? Now you can do `QueryData.OrderBy(a => a.customer[0].OtherAddress)`.

Comment: @NetMage i need to sort the parent nodes not an sibling alone.
QueryData.Select(a => new { a, TempData = a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0] }).OrderBy(a => a.TempData).Select(a => a.a); I sorting a original data based on temp data. Then i split the original data alone.

Comment: @Icepickle I have update my code.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Even if you could achieve what you want to achieve, it makes no sense. If the anonymous object's properties were dynamically added, that means you can never know for sure than a (finalized) object has a certain property or not. Anonymous types, while they do not require a formal class definition, are still **strongly typed** (i.e. their properties (including a property's type) are **definitively** known at compile time). What is the **actual problem** you're trying to solve?

Comment: Hi @Flater I have updated my question If i sort the OtherAddress field 0th index means Customer field only sorted. I need to sort the whole order data based on OtherAddress field.

Comment: @karthik: Either I'm misunderstanding you, or your answer is not answering the issue I raised in my comment. Regardless, I'm already drafting an answer that should help you along. Give me a minute :)

Comment: @Flater ok sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### XY problem?

This feels like it's a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your solution is contrived (no offense intended), and the problem you're trying to solve is not apparent by observing your proposed solution.

However, I do think there is technical merit to your question when I read *the intention of your code* as opposed to your *described* intention.

---

### Redundant steps

```
IQueryable abc = QueryData
                    .Select(a => new { 
                             a, 
                             TempData = a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0] })
                    .OrderBy(a => a.TempData)
                    .Select(a => a.a);
```

First of all, when you **inline** this into a single chained command, `TempData` becomes a redundant step. You could simply shift the first `TempData` logic (from the first `Select`) directly into the `OrderBy` lambda:

```
IQueryable abc = QueryData
                    .OrderBy(a => a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0])
                    .AsQueryable();
```

As you can see, this also means that you no longer need the second `Select` (since it existed only to undo the earlier `Select`)

---

### Parametrization and method abstraction

You mentioned you're looking for a usage similar to:

```
PerformComplexDataOperation(datasource, "customer.0.OtherAddress")
```

However, this doesn't quite make sense, since you've defined an **extension method**:

```
private static IQueryable PerformComplexDataOperation<T>(this IQueryable<T> dataSource, string select)
```

I think you need to reconsider your intended usage, and also the method as it is currently defined.

- Minor note, the return type of the method should be `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IQueryable`. Otherwise, you lose the generic type definition that LINQ tends to rely on.
- Based on the method signature, your expected usage should be `myData = myData.PerformComplexDataOperation("customer.0.OtherAddress")`.
- Strings are easy hacks to allow you to circumvent an otherwise strongly typed system. While your strign usage is technically functional, it is **non-idiomatic** and it **opens the door to unreadable and/or bad code**.
- Using strings leads to a contrived string parsing logic. Look at your method definition, and count how many lines are there simply to parse the string and translate that into actual code again.
- Strings also mean that you get no Intellisense, which can cause unseen bugs further down the line.

So let's not use strings. Let's look back at how I initially rewrote the `OrderBy:

```
.OrderBy(a => a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0])
```

When you consider `OrderBy` as an ordinary method, no different from any custom method you and I can develop, then you should understand that `a => a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0]` is nothing more than a **parameter** that's being passed.

The type of this parameter is `Func<A,B>`, where:

- `A` equals the type of your entity. So in this case, `A` is the same as `T` in your existing method.
- `B` equals the type of your **sorting value**.

  - `OrderBy(x => x.MyIntProp)` means that `B` is of type `int`.
  - `OrderBy(x => x.MyStringProp)` means that `B` is of type `string`.
  - `OrderBy(x => x.Customer)` means that `B` is of type `Customer`.

Generally speaking, the type of `B` doesn't matter for you (since it will only be used by LINQ's internal ordering method).

Let's look at a very simple extension method that uses a **parameter** for its `OrderBy`:

```
    public static IQueryable<A> OrderData<A, B>(this IQueryable<A> data, Func<A, B> orderbyClause)
    {
        return data
                .OrderBy(orderbyClause)
                .AsQueryable();
    }
```

Using the method looks like:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> myData = GetData(); //assume this returns a correct value

myData = myData.OrderData(x => x.MyIntProperty);
```

Notice how I did not need to specify either of the generic type arguments when calling the method.

- `A` is already known to be `MyEntity`, because we're calling the method on an object of type `IQueryable<MyEntity>`.
- `B` is already known to be an `int`, since the used lambda method returns a value of type `int` (from `MyIntProperty`)

As it stands, my example method is just a boring wrapper that does nothing different from the existing `OrderBy` method. But you can change the method's logic to suit your needs, and actually make it meaningfully different from the existing `OrderBy` method.

---

### Your expectations

Your description of your goals makes me think that you're expecting too much.

> **I need to sort** "customer.0.OtherAddress" **nested file compared to whole base data**. But it sorted only for that field. For this case, I find that field value and stored it to TempData. Then Sorting the TempData field.
>
> **i need to sort the parent nodes not an sibling alone.** QueryData.Select(a => new { a, TempData = a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0] }).OrderBy(a => a.TempData).Select(a => a.a); I sorting a original data based on temp data. Then i split the original data alone.

It's not possible to sort an entire nested data structure based on a *single* `OrderBy` call. `OrderBy` only sorts the collection on which you call `Orderby`, nothing else.

If you have a list of `Customer` entities, who each have a list of `Adress` entities, then you are working with many lists (a list of customer and several lists of adresses). `OrderBy` will only sort the list that you ask it to sort, it will not look for any nested lists.

You mention that your `TempData` solution works. I actually wrote an entire answer contesting that notion (it should be functionally similar to my suggested alternatives, and it should always order the original list, not any nested list), until I noticed that you've made it work for a very insidious and non-obvious reason:

```
.Select(a => new { 
                a, 
                TempData = a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0] 
        })
```

You are calling `.ToList()`, which changes how the code behaves. You started off with an `IQueryable<>`, which means that LINQ was preparing an SQL command to retrieve the data **when you enumerate it**.
This is the goal of an `IQueryable<>`. Instead of pulling all the data into memory and then filtering it according to your specifications, it instead constructs a complex SQL query, and will then only need to execute a single (constructed) query.

The execution of that constructed query occurs when you try to access the data (obviously, the data needs to be fetched if you want to access it). A common method of doing so is by **enumerating** the `IQueryable<>` into an `IEnumerable<>`.

This is what you've done in the `Select` lambda. Instead of asking LINQ to enumerate your list of orders, you've asked it to enumerate **every list of addresses** from every customer from every order in the list of orders.

But in order to know which adresses need to be enumerated, LINQ must first know which customers it's supposed to get the adresses from. And to find out which customers it needs, it must first figure out which orders you're working with. The only way it can figure all of that out is by **enumerating everything**.

My initial suggestion, that you should avoid using the `TempData` solution, is still valid. It's a redundant step that serves no functional purpose. However, the **enumeration** that also takes place may actually be of use to you here, because it changes LINQ's behavior slightly. You claim that it fixes your problem, so I'm going to take your statement at face value and assume that the slightly different behavior between LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Entities solves your problem.

You can keep the enumeration and still omit the `TempData` workaround:

```
IQueryable abc = QueryData
                    .OrderBy(a => a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0])
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .AsQueryable();
```

Some footnotes:

- You can use `ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable()`, the result is the same.
- When you use `First()` or `Single()`, enumeration will inherently take place, so you don't need to call `AsEnumerable()` beforehand.
- Notice that I cast the result to an `IEnumerable<>`, but then I immediately re-cast it to `IQueryable<>`. **Once a collection has been enumerated, any further operation on it will occur in-memory**. Casting it back to an `IQueryable<>` does not change the fact that the collection has already been enumerated.

---

### But does it work?

Now, I think that this still doesn't sort all of your nested lists with a single call. However, **you claim it does**. If you still believe that it does, then you don't need to read on (because your problem is solved). Otherwise, the following may be useful to you.

SQL, and by extension LINQ, has made it possible to sort a list based on information that is not found in the list. This is essentially what you're doing, you're asking LINQ to sort **a list of orders** based on a related address (regardless of whether you want the adresses to be retrieved from the database or not!) You're not asking it to sort the customers, or the addresses. You're only asking it to sort the **orders**.

Your sort logic feels a bit dirty to me. You are supplying an `Address` entity to your `OrderBy` method, without specifiying any of its (value type) properties. But how are you expecting your addresses to be sorted? By alphabetical street name? By database id? ...

I would expect you to be more explicit about what you want, e.g. `OrderBy(x => x.Address.Street).ThenBy(x => x.Address.HouseNumber)` (this is a simplified example).

After enumeration, since all the (relevant) data is in-memory, you can start ordering all the nested lists. For example:

```
foreach(var order in myOrders)
{
    order.Customer.Addresses = order.Customer.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.Street).ToList();
}
```

This orders all the lists of addresses. **It does not change the order of the list of orders**.

Do keep in mind that if you want to order data in-memory, that you do in fact need the data to be present in-memory. If you never loaded the customer's addresses, you can't use addresses as a sorting argument.

- Ordering the list of **orders** should be done *before* enumeration. It's generally faster to have it handled by your SQL database, which is what happens when you're working with LINQ-to-SQL.
- Ordering nested lists should be done *after* enumeration, because the order of these lists is unrelated to the original `IQueryable<Order>`, which only focused on sorting the orders, not its nested related entities (during enumeration, the included entities such as `Customer` and `Address` are retrieved without ordering them).

Comment: @karthik: You're welcome. Sorry about the length :) But I suspect part of the issue is that you're working based off of some false (but understandable) assumptions, which makes it hard to accurately gauge the solution without explicitly refuting those assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your `OrderBy` so you don't need an anonymous type (though I like the Perl/Lisp Schwartzian Transform) and then it is straightforward to create dynamically (though I am not sure how dynamically you mean).

Using the new expression:

```
var abc = QueryData.OrderBy(a => a.customer[0].OtherAddress);
```

Not being sure what you mean by dynamic, you can create the lambda

```
x => x.OrderBy(a => a.customer[0].Otheraddress)
```

using Expression as follows:

```
var parmx = Expression.Parameter(QueryData.GetType(), "x");
var parma = Expression.Parameter(QueryData[0].GetType(), "a");
var abc2 = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(MyExtensions.GetMethodInfo((IEnumerable<Orders> x)=>x.OrderBy(a => a.customer[0].OtherAddress)),
                                             new Expression[] { parmx,
                                                                Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(Expression.ArrayIndex(Expression.Property(parma, "customer"), Expression.Constant(0)), "OtherAddress"), parma) }),
                             parmx);
```

Comment: i need to sort the parent nodes not an sibling alone. QueryData.Select(a => new { a, TempData = a.customer.Select(b => b.OtherAddress).ToList()[0] }).OrderBy(a => a.TempData).Select(a => a.a); I sorting a original data based on temp data. Then i split the original data alone.